# Can anyone identify this Hasbro part? 2x2 circle with a ball on a short bar

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Description: A 2x2 round tile with a ball sticking out in the middle of it, the ball being slightly smaller than a LEGO axle with ball. I’ve searched Bricklink extensively before, and the brick has Hasbro written on it, which has led me to believe it is a Kre-O brick of some kind.

[image: Hasbro piece]

Comment: Definitely not Lego, as you saw. I have this part (I saved it in my "interesting non-Lego pieces") but I don't know from what set(s) it originally came.

Comment: One of mine says 38955-009-01 (which I assume is a manufacturing code to track malformed pieces back to the factory it came from) and 10162 (which I assume is an actual part number). Neither identifier seems to help.

Answer (score 6):

[image: KRE-O 10162]

This is the **KRE-O 10162**, which first appeared in a blue version from the early version of [KRE-O Transformers Optimus Prime Dino Hauler](https://kreo.fandom.com/wiki/Optimus_Prime_Dino_Hauler), working as a ball for the midsection of the truck. Sadly, this has later been altered to be black.

White and gray versions can be found below:
USS Missouri:
https://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/6d0a17b55056900b100f781b9c2c69e3/0A1109CC5056900B103B5B36EBB8C6D3.pdf

Stealth Bumblebee:
https://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/6d0a17b55056900b100f781b9c2c69e3/F0B345F05056900B10DF528BB37A0AB9.pdf

I'm having trouble discerning from your photo if the piece is gray, blue, or white, but my guess is that yours is from the USS Missouri.